# How to use 2 yield items from 2 different methods in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python and scrapy. I am yielding 2 items from 2 different methods, first one is for first-page data, the second one is for second-page data. I am not able to save the data in same order, the second item saving after the first item, but I need to save both at a time.
    Thanks in advance.

```
class FirstPipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
        filename = 'License_Vehicle Inspection Stations_NY_CurationReady_' + current_date +'_v1.csv'
        self.file = open(filename, 'w+b')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file, delimiter = '|')

        self.exporter.csv_writer.writerow(["Premises Name","Principal's Name","","Trade Name","Zone","County","Address/zone","License Class","License Type Code","License Type","Expiration Date","License Status","Serial Number","Credit Group","Filing Date","Effective Date"," "," "," "," "])
        self.exporter.fields_to_export = ["company_name","mixed_name","mixed_subtype","dba_name","zone","county","location_address_string","licence_class","licence_type_code","permity_subtype","permit_lic_exp_date","permit_licence_status","permit_lic_no","credit_group","permit_lic_eff_date","permit_applied_date","permit_type","url","source_name","ingestion_timestamp"]
        self.exporter.start_exporting()


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print("got the item in pipeline")
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

class SecondPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, SecondItem):
            pass

        return item
```

Answer (score 1):

Raj725, your question is actual for beginners in Scrapy and may be in Python. I had same question before I read Scrapy documentation. It's not possible to understand Scrapy without reading documentation. You can start to read [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), then Item section and Pipeline section.

It's example how to yield several type of data.

1 Need to prepair Items you need in items.py file:

```
from scrapy import Item, Field

class FirstItem(Item):
    field_one = Field()
    field_two = Field()

class SecondItem(Item):
    another_field_one = Field()
    another_field_two = Field()
    another_field_three = Field()
```

2 Now you can use Items in your scrapy code. It's possible to yield Items in any place where you have data to save:

```
from ..items import FirstItem, SecondItem

        item = FirstItem(
            field_one=response.css("div.one span::text").extract_first(),
            field_two=response.css("div.two span::text").extract_first()
        )
        yield item

        item = SecondItem(
            another_field_one='some variable one',
            another_field_one='some variable two',
            another_field_three='some variable tree'
        )
        yield item
```

3 Example of pipeline.py file. Do not forgot to check type of Item before saving it. In the end of "process_item" you have to return item.

```
from .items import FirstItem, SecondItem

class FirstPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, FirstItem):            
            # Save your data here. It's possible to save it to CSV file. Also you can put data to any database you need.
            pass

        return item

class SecondPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, SecondItem):            
            # Save your data here. It's possible to save it to CSV file. Also you can put data to any database you need.
            pass

        return item
```

4 Do no forgot to declare your Pipelines in settings.py. Scrapy will not use Pilelines without it.

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
     'scrapy_project.pipelines.FirstPipeline': 300,
     'scrapy_project.pipelines.SecondPipeline': 300,
}
```

I do not provided ready to use code. I provided examples of code to understand how it work. It's possible to put it to your code and make changes you need.
I didn't show how to save Items to CSV files. You can import "csv" module. Also you can use CsvItemExported in your [pipeline.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668209/why-does-my-scrapy-spider-only-scrape-some-of-my-data/50669389#50669389) from "scrapy.exporters". I provided  link with example how to save different Items to different CSV files.

Comment: Thank you @Oleg T. Really it is helped a lot, but in CSV file I can't save in same way. The second item saving after the first item.

Comment: I see that you provided your pileline.py file to review. You can see my previous unswer regard [save data to several CSV files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668209/why-does-my-scrapy-spider-only-scrape-some-of-my-data/50669389#50669389)

Comment: I saw your code, And I used it in my pipeline. And it shows error as below. self.exporter['second'].export_item(item)
TypeError: 'CsvItemExporter' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I didn't find how to reach same error in my side. Could you provide code?